# Java Servlets + JDBC + Postgres: How does it all interact?

Tags: postgresql, servlets, jdbc

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to use servlets properly

I've set up a postgres database, and downloaded a JDBC driver for it.

What I want to have is my webpages post to the servlet, and the servlet get info from the database. I understand how to code everything (eg add library for driver, open connections, execute queries), but I think I'm lacking knowledge in how to set up the file structure.

I have the postgresql database running on pgAdmin. Do I also need to have a server running to make the servlets work as well? Can't I just make a web.xml file that maps to the servlets, and open the webpages to use the website? If I run the project through an IDE with a server running (glassfish) everything works. If I close the IDE and go to open the webpages on my browser again, I get 404's whenever I submit to a servlet.

Can someone give me a bit of guidance on the big picture of how everything is supposed to interact (with details on servers please). I've been searching the web and I havent found anything that explains the big picture very well.

Thanks

Comment: from where your server is started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java web application is a set of files obeying a well-defined structure, and which can be packaged in a war file.

This web application is deployed into a server (also called container), which understands the file structure, listens to HTTP requests, and calls the appropriate servlet of the appropriate deployed web application when it receives one.

And of course, if you shut down the server, nothing listens to the HTTP requests anymore, so you won't get any response.

You could read the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/geysj.html) for more explanations.